# How to implement network free drawing with Fabric.js and ASP.Net Core SignalR?

Tags: javascript, c#, fabricjs, asp.net-core-signalr

**Note:** I am writing this program using C# backend and JavaScript front end, however this question is probably only going to apply to a niche group of users that are familiar with both Fabric.js and ASP.Net Core Signalr (**not** ASP.Net Signalr).

I am trying to implement a multiplayer free drawing kind of game (think: online whiteboard where all the users can see someone draw on the board, in real time). I have implemented a single player whiteboard (think: canvas that allows free drawing) using Fabric.js, and I also have implemented a simple chat program using ASP.Net Core Signalr (**not** ASP.Net Signalr).  I am trying to connect the two so that I can get a multiplayer whiteboard, but I am stuck on getting the canvas updated on all the users' screen.  I have done research online, and there are examples that do what I want to do (see: http://drawsignal.azurewebsites.net/), but using ASP.Net Signalr, not ASP.Net Core Signalr.  The two are different and incompatible (source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-2.2 )  Thus I am stuck on what to do.

I have provided my code below.  If anyone can provide a working example of a multiplayer canvas using Fabric.JS and ASP.Net Core Signalr, it would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Fabric.JS Free drawing:

```
document.getElementById("drawButtonStart").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    canvas.isDrawingMode = true; //this allows free drawing on canvas
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Chat Room with ASP.Net Core SignalR (client side javascript code):

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();

connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
    var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    var encodedMsg = user + " says " + msg;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = encodedMsg;
    document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
});
```

Server side chat room:

```
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you indicate where you're stuck? You seem to have the client/server communication set up? Surely you just need to share changes with the clients by sending it through SignalR?

Comment: Using the .NET vs the CORE version of signalr makes no difference. I'm not familiar with fabric.js but I can already see how there would be issues keeping the canvas in sync if two or more people were drawing at the same time. Following their chat tutorial, you should be able to just replace the chat text with your canvas data and it should be pretty straightforward. I would start out by just getting your drawing to show up in another window (or another computer. whatever). That part should be very straighforward.

Comment: I can send chat messages between clients, but the free drawing does not send between clients.  Only the client that draws can see their own drawing.

Comment: If you were to replace the 'drawing' with just a word or something like 'user is currently drawing...', does that come through?

Comment: I am stuck on replacing the chat text with my canvas data.  That is the main issue I am having as it does not seem to send.

Comment: Since Fabric.js' free drawing does not become an object until the user **stops** drawing, I do not know exactly how to pass it as a parameter.  See: http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-4#free_drawing  where it says 'You can paint as many times on canvas as you wish, while isDrawingMode is true. But as soon as you perform any movement, followed by a "mouseup" event, Fabric fires "path:created" event and actually transforms just-drawn shape into a real fabric.Path instance!'

Comment: If you have a repo that I can pull down to take a look, I'd be willing to do so. From the looks of your first code snippet, it's not clear how your emiting/broadcasting to the hub. Looks like you've just got a click even that enables someone to draw.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196950/discussion-between-aiyuni-and-mwilson).